# DraggableScrollableSheet but not scrollable

Tags: flutter

I need a DraggableSheet but not scrollable, so it does not require any scrollable widget inside it.
What I need is a DraggableSheet that only scrollable until it expands and not the content inside.
is there any native widget or 3rd party library for it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the builder for the `DraggableScrollableSheet` requires you to return a `Scrollable` widget, you could return a `ListView` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` assigned to the physics argument. Or any other widget you require that allows you to set the physics to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`

More info and code samples on the [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

More info and code samples on the [NeverScrollPhysics docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html)

Comment: it will disable the dragging of the DraggableScrollableSheet

Comment: @SinaMN75 Okay will look into the docs for more information, I am unable to access a flutter environment to test a solution. 

Perhaps your could update your question with the options your have already tried?

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to just using a `Container` ?

Comment: Yes , but DraggableScrollableSheet is only draggable when there's a scrollable widget inside it.